# How to make xdotool auto-click repeatedly?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, xdotool

How to make xdotool auto-click repeatedly where I place the cursor? 
I need the auto-click to start when I press the left button of the mouse + a key, for example AltGr. And to stop when I leave the key.

I am newbie in  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. Please, give me clear instructions through steps. Thank you!

---

Comment: Instead of editing your Question to include the answer, it would be better to post an Answer. You can answer your own questions on this site and it helps other people to find it more easily.

Comment: I had done it before to an other question, but my answer was removed. Do you think it is better to edit again and post it as an answer?

Comment: A valid answer should not be removed. This is a QA site, questions and answers should be separated to help people find information easier.

Comment: OK. I'll do it and see what happens.... Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after reading around and experiment. So, I post it here for others who might need help with the same issue.

**Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts >** (Scroll down) **Custom Shortcuts >** Click on **+** and create new shortcut with the attributes:

**Name:** Auto-click (or whatever you want) 

**Command:** xdotool click 1 

**Shortcut:** press a combination of keys. Some keys might not work because they are bound by the system. Try an other combination. Done!